# Drupal Commerce + Taxonomy

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I want to create a taxonomy based catalog for my products.
The first step would be to create the taxonomy tree for my products:

- term 1

  - term 1.1
  - term 1.2
- term 2

  - term 2.1
- term 3

But then I need to create my product catalog page. The question there is actually which technique is the best to achieve what I need.
On top op my products page I want to list all my parent terms (term 1, term 2 & term 3) with a count of the products that are listed in that category OR their subcategories. When I click such a term I need it to filter out my product list to display only the products which are tagged with that term or one of the child terms.

What is best practice to achieve this kind of functionality? Do I use Taxonomy Menu or do I generate some views and make them communicate with each other (through links with get paramaters for example)?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just create a single view with a contextual filter by taxonomy term id, then create an 'Attachment' for that view that pulls in the same contextual filter and lists child terms based on that...can't think of an easier way to be honest

Comment: "I want to list all my parent terms (term 1, term 2 & term 3) with a count of the products that are listed in that category OR their subcategories" ===> Any thoughts on the count for the nodes?   
The product display can be achieved by using the "Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)" contextual filter and the taxonomy_display module I think.

Answer (score 0):

This one block can be implemented with Views as Clive suggested. However, if you want more than that, you should have a look at the [facet API](https://drupal.org/project/facetapi) module which can be used to implement faceted search interfaces.